# Connecting two tables with a sub-select also with empty rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got two tables: trx, with transactions and events with events. 
`trx.purchaseid` = foreignkey with `events.id`

I'm trying to create a relation with a tuple for every transaction and one field from the events table.

```
SELECT trx.*,
    ( SELECT open FROM events AS ev
      WHERE ev.id = trx.purchaseid
    ) AS open
FROM trx
```

Works perfect. But sometimes there isn't a event row with that same id. The subselect returns 0 rows. The field `open` results in `0`.
But the values of open can be 1|0.

Is there a way to alter this query to let the `open` field contain 1|0|NULL instead of 1|0|0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a `JOIN`.  Even in your example, you could use an `INNER JOIN` instead of a sub-query.

In this case, you want a `LEFT JOIN`, to include the `NULL`

```
SELECT trx.*, open
FROM trx
LEFT JOIN events AS ev
ON ev.id = trx.purchaseid
```